# How to tell curl to check file existence before download?

Tags: bash, curl

I use this command to download a series of images:

```
curl -O --max-time 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 http://site.com/image[0-100].jpg
```

Some images are corrupted, so I delete them.

```
for i in *.jpg; do jpeginfo -c $i || rm $i; done
```

How to tell `curl` to check file existence before download?

I can use this command to prevent `curl`  override existing images:

```
chmod 000 *.jpg
```

But I don't want to re-download them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the target resource is static, `curl` has an option `-z` to only download a newer target copy.

Usage example:

```
curl -z image0.jpg http://site.com/image0.jpg
```

An example for your case:

`for i in $(seq 0 100); do curl -z image$i.jpg -O --max-time 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 http://site.com/image$i.jpg; done`

Comment: ... or with one command: curl --max-time 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 http://domain/image[0-100].jpg -O image#1.jpg -z image#1.jpg

Answer (score 7):

No idea about doing it with curl, but you could check it with Bash before you run the curl command.

```
for FILE in FILE1 FILE2 …
do
  if [[ ! -e $FILE ]]; then
    # Curl command to download the image.
  fi
done
```